# How to get a property from a Model when writing a display template

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-4, display-templates

I have a model...

```
public class PatientACOModel
{
    public int EncounterId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int EMPIID { get; set; }
    public int PopulationPatientID { get; set; }
    public string EditAddOrEditCurrent { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    //[UIHint("_PhoneNumFormatter")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to specifically format my phone numbers.  I just want to put a UIHint over my phone number and possibly other phone numbers.  I don't want all strings to be formatted.

I am trying things like this...

```
@Model String
@if (Model != null) {
    String.Format("{0: (###) ###-####}", double.Parse(Model.ModelMetadata.Get));
}
```

That would be the display template referenced in my UIHint that is commented out.
When I do that, none of my strings show up.  What am I doing wrong?

In my display template how do I get the string to parse and then Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would check if the `_PhoneNumFormatter` is defined in one of the following locations:

```
~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/_PhoneNumFormatter.cshtml
~/Views/<Controller>/DisplayTemplates/_PhoneNumFormatter.cshtml
```

Next I think you wanted to format the string value directly from the `Model` property:

```
@model String

@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model)) 
{
    @String.Format("{0: (###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(Model))
}
```

This should work fine with the `UIHint` attribute, I've just checked in a sample application.

Code assumes that numbers in your region don't start with a leading 0 and that the `Model` property will contain strings containing only numeric characters, if not you should improve the `Convert.ToInt64` part.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what I am getting when I try that.
'4124880798 String'

Comment: IE it is not formatted and I just have String at the end of the phone number... I have this in display templates by the way

Comment: It seems like it still does not hit the _PhoneNumFormatter template. Could you try and add a `<span>phone:</span>` just before the `@String.Format` part to see if it actually tries to format the Model?

Comment: Forgot my @ in front of my @String.Format

Comment: dumb question... Sometimes I get () - and other times a get empty strings... Any idea why that happens?  Maybe I should check for String.Empy

Comment: I've updated the answer for completeness, the code will also fail for strings containing non-numeric characters. You could check that as well.